# How to select multiple file in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to write an application program that allow you to select multiple file through FileUpload in ASP.NET using C#, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the allowmultiple property

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
```

Take a look at [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/upload-multiple-files-using-fileupload-control-in-Asp-Net-4/)

Answer (score 2):

.NET 4.5 & above :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
```

.NET 4 and below :

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="fileImages" Multiple="Multiple" runat="server" />
```

html :

```
<div>
    <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="uploadedFile" Text="Upload" OnClick="uploadFile_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="listofuploadedfiles" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Button click code :

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
       {
           uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"),
           uploadedFile.FileName)); listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br />", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
}
```

more [reference](http://www.encodedna.com/2013/02/multiple-file-upload-in-aspdotnet.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You just could write a Submit Controller Method like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Submit(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    //your file code here 
}
```

and then just offering a corresponding view with any widget for the upload you like and post back the files. e.g. Jquery file upload widget: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Kendo Ui example in ASP.NET MVC:

```
 <form method="post" action='@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new {Action =     "Submit"})' style="width:45%">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="float-left">
    //widget here 
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="k-button" />
        </p>
    </div>
  </form>
```